# I want to stream a ZIP archive via koa/node.js

Tags: koa, node-archiver

i want to stream a ZIP file, but I can not get the `stream` to work in `Koa`. Here is what I have so far (simplified)

```html
import Stream from 'stream'
import archiver from 'archiver'

...

 router.get('/zip', async ctx => {

   ctx.set('Content-Type', 'application/zip')

   const content = 'Hey there!'
    
   const archive = archiver('zip', {
      zlib: { level: 9 }, 
   })

   const stream = new Stream.Duplex()
   ctx.body = stream


   archive.pipe(stream)
   archive.append(content, { name: `hello.txt` })
   archive.finalize()
})
```

However, I get this error:

`Error [ERR_METHOD_NOT_IMPLEMENTED]: The _read() method is not implemented`

What do i miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently

```
const stream = new Stream.PassThrough()
```

does the trick :)

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm!